# Change height of element on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys I'm trying to change height of my element dynamically.
These are my variables.

```
var windowWidth = 1440;
var currentWidth = $(window).width();
var elementHeight = $('#line4').height();
```

Now what I want is when difference between window width and current width is lower then 6 I want to change height of my element. I want to do this every time when (windowWidth - currentWidth)<6. So every time when window resizes and it's lower then 6 I want to change height of element by minus 14px. This is what I've tried.

```
$( window ).bind("resize", function(){
    if((windowWidth - currentWidth)<6) {
        $("#line4").css('height', elementHeight-14);
    }
});
```

It does not work and I don't know what I'm missing. Also follow up question can I change other CSS properties this way. For this particular problem I will also need to change css `top` property in the same way, because I have some div with absolute position.

Comment: You must put `currentWidth` and `elementHeight` into the resize function, if `windowWidth` isn't constant as in your example, also this

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure the current width of the window on every resize event, since it's changing too.

```
var windowWidth = 1440;
var currentWidth = $(window).width();
var elementHeight = $('#line4').height();

$( window ).bind("resize", function(){
  currentWidth = $(window).width()
  if((windowWidth - currentWidth)<6) {
    $("#line4").css('height', elementHeight-14);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not my code originally and it's a mess. I've tried uploading it on codepen and jsbin but it doesn't work properly. Here you can check it on my google drive. What my trying to change is one of the modals. There are lines there that are connecting my divs and it's for them that i need to change height. Drive link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6qR8Uzr3ojCVlQyRVRDWUZQcW8

Comment: Here's a working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZPGXV?editors=1111
Please add your simplified project in a pen instead of a zip please.

Comment: I've just checked you codepen when I'm resizing screen nothing happens height stays the same. Here is an image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzFnmSPdntJDaFV4dk5kTXpGYms/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It reduces the height of the element when your window is bigger than 1440px. Try to resize it to bigger. But if you try to explain your whole problem with a codepen, we can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get windowWidth each time resize event called
And you should add debounce into `resize` event for better performance.
I often do like this, maybe you can search any better way:

```
var resizeTimer;
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {

  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

  // Run code here, resizing has "stopped"
  currentWidth = $(window).width()
  if((windowWidth - currentWidth)<6) {
    $("#line4").css('height', elementHeight-14);
  }

  }, 250);
});
```

and I created this to test, you can try it. Btw i increase from 6 to 600 to check easier :D
https://codepen.io/huytran0605/pen/NgBEVO

Comment: I've just checked you codepen when I'm resizing screen nothing happens height stays the same. Here is an image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzFnmSPdntJDTU9ZU1RWZnlSWDA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please check by google dev tool and inspect into that element.

Comment: Here you can see it height is still the same even on resize:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6qR8Uzr3ojCdXp6MUJGX3NIcm8

Comment: it's still working on my machine. Please check the console, What does message show? I think the problem does not come from the code. Or you can use another browser?